# Qt and QtRegExp for parsing html tags

Tags: regex, qt

I want to parse out html tag name. My code is this:

```
QRegExp exp("<\\s*(\\w+)\\s*");
exp.indexIn("<html> hi there </html>");
qDebug() << exp.cap(1);
```

It's logging "h" instead of "html". Why? As far as I understand it, the \w+ should find a string with one  *or more* word characters, in this case "html". But since it's not, what would be the right way to achive this?

Comment: "<\\s*(\\b\\w+\\b)\\s*", Thanks Avinash Raj, works as a dream!

Comment: Just be aware that you can't parse arbitrary HTML with regular expressions, as HTML is a context-free language.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using indexIn without iterating the matches and you aren't using the capturing groups to access to your captured data.

Use this code instead:

```
QRegExp rx("<\\s*(\\w+)\\s*");
QString str = "<html> hi there </html>";
QStringList list;
int pos = 0;

while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
    list << rx.cap(1);
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}

// list: ["html"]
```

Comment: oops, yea a small typo in question. Was meaning qDebug() << exp.cap(1);

Comment: @olltsu I saw that you updated the question with other content and Avi's comment answered your question.